# Unable to use "useState" functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React functional component with a `useState` hook.

I used this function component as src to to a script tag inside `index.html`.
when I add a `render` method at the end of this functional component, it throws an error saying invalid hooks.

I have created an `index.html` where I have assigned `welcome.js` as the source to a script tag. When this script executes, it calls function `welcome.js`. 
In the `Welcome` function if I use a state hook it throws an error:

> "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

```
<script src="./Welcome.js"> </script>
```

`welcome.js`:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";

const Welcome = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("name");

    return(
        <div>     
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>       
            <input
             id="name"
             value={name}
             onChange= {e=>setName(e.target.value)}
             >
            </input>
        </div>
    )
}

render(<Welcome/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I'd like to know why I can't use state hook inside `welcome.js` here. Can we not use state hooks along with the `render` method?

Comment: @MeetZaveri `render` is imported from `react-dom`

Comment: Yes it was a mistake

Comment: @AyyappaGollu what version of react is this? what is your bundler? [**I can't reproduce it**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-cyj40)

Comment: @JohnRuddell i am using react@16.8.6. Parcel bundler.

Comment: @MeetZaveri may i know what was the mistake ? import render i am using is completely correct syntax.

Comment: Can you set up a reproducible example? You can use https://codesandbox.io/ for example

Comment: Is there a chance that you might use two or more different versions of react? This is a [known problem](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) in that case.

Comment: @MotiKorets here is the linke for codesandbox.io : https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-waterfall-sm97v. you can see index.html, Welcome.js file which are modified by me.

Comment: Here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-shtern-k5xj7

Comment: do you have `react-hot-loader` enabled? it does not work with hooks: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088

Answer (score 3):

The code inside the component is valid. The problem lies with either dependency problem or a build tool configuration. Make sure

1. You have react-dom version bigger 16.8.0 ( run `npm ls react-dom`)
2. You have only one version of react imported. ( run `npm ls react`)

Here is a link to [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-carson-9xz9v) with the code you provided.
Pay attention to pakcage.json file.
More details in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Comment: why _You have react-dom version bigger 16.8.0_ ? afaik hooks worked fine started from 16.3 or something like that

Comment: check the link to the documentation

Comment: @MotiKorets hi Moti korets thanks for your help. i created new project and used same files again, surprisingly it worked. i guess my code is valid. also i checked no of react apps running, it's only one.